# Run terminal script in python?

Tags: python, shell, terminal, subprocess, popen

I am using python and I am trying to run a shell script that is located in another folder I am trying

`subprocess.call(['source','../Apps/appName/run'])`

Where 'run' is a shell script I wrote and made an executable. But it keeps giving errors such as

**No such file or directory** or **No such file or directory: "source"

I have also tried the following

`subprocess.call(['source','../Apps/appName/run'])` 
`subprocess.call(['source ../Apps/appName/run'])` 
`subprocess.call(['.','../Apps/appName/run'])`

I am trying to run the script and leave it alone (as in I do not want any return value or to see what the output of the shell script is.

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you do `which source` in your terminal, what does it tell you? Have you tried pitting in `/usr/bin/source` instead? It looks like python isn't looking at the right place for the `source` executable, so you might have to tell it that.

Comment: I tried adding the full path to source but it still says no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

`source` is a shell builtin that reads a file and interprets the commands in the current shell instance. It's similar to C `#include` or Python `import`. You should not be using it to run shell scripts.

The correct way to run a script is to add a shebang like `#!/bin/bash` to the first line, and `chmod +x yourscriptfile`. The OS will then consider it a real executable, which can be executed robustly from any context. In Python, you would do:

```
subprocess.call(['../Apps/appName/run'])
```

If for whichever reason this is not an option, you can instead explicitly invoke `bash` on the file, since this is similar to what would happen if you're in bash and type `source`:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', '../Apps/appName/run'])
```